# React Increment all counters at once: how to reuse handler function for multiple component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, counter

I have 3 counter buttons but I want a separate button that will onClick increment all the counters by 1. What is the best way to implement it and to have the state change all of the counters at once? I tried adding a `countAll` and combining all the counts but the syntax seemed off and I am not sure how to do it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from './components/Button';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { counter1: 0, counter2: 0, counter3: 0 };
}

incrementCount1() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ counter1: prevState.counter1 + 1 }));
}

incrementCount2() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ counter2: prevState.counter2 + 1 }));
}

incrementCount3() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ counter3: prevState.counter3 + 1 }));
}

decrementCount1() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ counter1: prevState.counter1 - 1 }));
}

decrementCount2() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ counter2: prevState.counter2 - 1 }));
}

decrementCount3() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ counter3: prevState.counter3 - 1 }));
}

render() {
  let { counter1, counter2, counter3 } = this.state

  return (
    <div className="App">

      <h2>Count: { counter1 }</h2>
      <Button title = { "+" } task = { () => this.incrementCount1(counter1) } />
      <Button title = { "-" } task = { () => this.decrementCount1(counter1) } />

      <h2>Count: { counter2 }</h2>
      <Button title = { "+" } task = { () => this.incrementCount2(counter2) } />
      <Button title = { "-" } task = { () => this.decrementCount2(counter2) } />

      <h2>Count: { counter3 }</h2>
      <Button title = { "+" } task = { () => this.incrementCount3(counter3) } />
      <Button title = { "-" } task = { () => this.decrementCount3(counter3) } />
    </div>

  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like @keikai's solution for code reduction/DRY-principal, but if you didn't want to change your existing state shape, **AND** if your existing state is *only* counters, then this would do the trick by operating over the state *as an object*.

Takes the state object, converts to array of entries, and reduces them back to an object that represents the next state with all counters incremented by the `incrementBy` amount.

```
incrementAll(incrementBy = 0) {
  this.setState(prevState =>
    Object.entries(prevState).reduce((counters, [counterKey, count]) => {
      counters[counterKey] = count + incrementBy;
      return counters;
    }, {})
  );
}
```

Usage

```
<Button title = { "+ all" } task = { () => this.incrementAll(1) } />
<Button title = { "- all" } task = { () => this.incrementAll(-1) } />
```

[image: Edit angry-mclaren-0nv8t]

Comment: Thanks this is what I was seeking.

Answer (score 2):

Sample using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) and [public class fields syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

```
countOperation = (field, diff) => () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ [field]: prevState[field] + diff }));
};

<button title={"+"} onClick={this.countOperation("counter1", 1)} />
<button title={"-"} onClick={this.countOperation("counter1", -1)} />
```

[image: Edit cocky-easley-z6yey]

---

#### Addition

If you like, you can make one step further to package the set of buttons to a common HOC which can return `id` on certain callback.

In this way, you won't need to bind the `index/key` for each of your elements multiple times if there are multiple callbacks.

```
countOperation = diff => (e, id) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ [id]: prevState[id] + diff }));
};

<CustomButton
  id="counter1"
  title={"+"}
  onClick={this.countOperation(1)}
/>

class CustomButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { id, title, onClick } = this.props;
    return <button title={title} onClick={e => onClick(e, id)} />;
  }
}
```

[image: Edit shy-smoke-55px1]

Comment: I think the `setState` needs to pass a callback in with `prevState` similar to the question to gracefully handle the updates.